# Testing an executable in a Python package

Tags: python, command-line-interface, package, setuptools, python-module

I'm a Ruby programmer working on my first  Python package (let's call it **foo**). Its primary purpose is as a command line tool. I'm specifying that it should be installed as an executable in `setup.py` using:

```
setup(
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = foo.cli:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

`foo/cli.py` contains:

```
import foo

def main():
    # program logic here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`cli.py` needs to reference `foo.__version__` which is defined in `foo/__init__.py`, but when I run `python foo/cli.py` locally to test the CLI, `import foo` raises `ImportError: No module named foo`. How do I get Python to see cli.py in the context of the foo package when running an individual file like this? Is my approach totally wrong? How do you normally go about testing an executable defined with setuptools's entry points locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing modifying the `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` variable to also include the directory where **foo/** resides.

On the command prompt before you run the **cli.py** file do the following

```
codepython@vm-0:~/python/foo$ PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/python/;export PYTHONPATH
```

Here in my setup **foo/** is present within **~/python** and the presence of **_*init*_.py** within **foo/** tells the python interpreter that **foo** is a package and not an ordinary directory.

Now you can `cd` into the **foo/** directory and then run `python cli.py`. You will be able to access the **foo** package methods and functions.

Alternatively within main() you can first modify the `sys.path` to append the directory containing **foo/** and then perform rest of the logic

To quote [Python documentation on Modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
>   PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
>   shell variable PATH). the installation-dependent default. After
>   initialization, Python programs can modify sys.path. The directory
>   containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the
>   search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that
>   scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the
>   same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the
>   replacement is intended. See section Standard Modules for more
>   information.

Comment: Very helpful - thank you! I added this to the top of the module: https://gist.github.com/jimmycuadra/6547407 Is this the canonical way of testing a CLI locally? Seems like kind of ugly boilerplate to have in the implementation code.

Comment: @JimmyCuadra Nope, you dont really need to do that. As I shown in my example, since you can modify the PYTHONPATH environment variable, you can write a simple shell script that modifies PYTHONPATH with the required directories and then executes the python script you want to test. This way you dont need to write that **ugly** boiler plate code within your script and your scripts can be tested from anywhere.

Comment: Is it standard to have a shell script wrapping test execution? I haven't seen anything like that in the open source Python libraries I've been looking at.

Comment: @JimmyCuadra I am not sure if that is a standard. What I provided was one way to solve your use case. However, I do not see anything **non-standard** in that - in case you have worked with Java, we do set our CLASSPATHs prior to executing tests from an ANT script. I guess, the same analogy can hold true here since you are testing your single script and not the whole setup program.

Answer (score 1):

Within the package, you can directly import `__init__` and then rename with `as`. Try this

```
import __init__ as foo
```

in place of

```
import foo
```

Comment: That worked! What if I also wanted to be able to access other modules in the foo package from inside cli.py? Say, if I also had a `foo/baz.py` file and I want to access a class called "MyClass" defined in it from within `foo/cli.py`? I tried `from .baz import MyClass` but got `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. Makes me think I am approaching the whole thing wrong.

Comment: For that example, I believe all you want is `from baz import MyClass`